# Suppose $\Delta$ is consistent, prove that $\Delta\cup\{A\}$ and $\Delta\cup\{\lnot A\}$ cannot be both consistent.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

**The Problem**: Suppose $\Delta$ is consistent, prove that $\Delta\cup\{A\}$ and $\Delta\cup\{\lnot A\}$ cannot be both consistent. Here $\Delta$ is set of propositional sentences, and $A$ is a sentence.

I am new to logic, and the problem arises while reading a proof of the Completeness Theorem: *If a theory $\Gamma$ is consistent, then $\Gamma$ is satisfiable*. In the proof,  the authors let $\Delta=\bigcup\Delta_n$ and $\Delta_n$ was defined recursively by $\Delta_0=\Gamma$,

$$\Delta_{n+1}=
\begin{cases}
\Delta_n\cup\{A_n\} \quad \text{if $\Delta_n\cup\{A_n\}$ is consistent,}  \\ 
\Delta_n\cup\{\lnot A_n\} \quad\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases} 
$$

For this $\Delta_n$ to be well-defined, our assumption must hold.

**My Attempt**: Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $\Delta\cup\{A\}$ and $\Delta\cup\{\lnot A\}$ are both consistent. Clearly we want to deduce that $\Gamma\vdash\bot$. Two lemmas come to mind:

***Lemma 1***: *For any theory $\Gamma$ and any sentence $A$, $\Gamma\vdash A$ iff $\Gamma\cup\{\lnot A\}$ is inconsistent*.

***Lemma 2***: *If a theory $\Gamma$ is consistent, they for any $A$, either $\Gamma\cup\{A\}$ is consistent or $\Gamma\cup\{\lnot A\}$ is consistent*.

But neither seems applicable. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this is a typo: I suspect that instead you're being asked to prove that we can't have both $\Delta\cup\{A\}$ and $\Delta\cup\{\neg A\}$ be **in**consistent. (The statement as written is false.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Hmmm. I added a bit more detail now to show why my assumption must hold.

Comment: We do not need the assertion for $\Delta_n$ to be well defined.  If both are consistent, $\Delta_{n+1}=\Delta_n \cup A_n$  We only get in trouble if both are inconsistent.

Comment: @RossMillikan If both are consistent, then $\Delta_{n+1}=\Delta_n\cup\{A_n\}$ and $\Delta_{n+1}$ also $=\Delta_n\cup\{\lnot A_n\}$. If $A_n\neq\lnot A_n$, then $\Delta_{n+1}$ would fail to be well-defined. But I assume you meant that if both are consistent then $A_n$ must be a special sentence such as $\bot$?

Comment: Presumably $A_n$ is not part of $\Delta_n$, so if you take the union $\Delta_{n+1}$ includes it and is different from $\Delta_n$.  If fact it can prove more than $\Delta_n$ because it can prove $A_n$

Comment: @RossMillikan I see. But note that the exactly same thing can be said about $\lnot A_n$, you then still get two different $\Delta_{n+1}$'s if both $\Delta_n\cup\{A_n\}$ and $\Delta_n\cup\{\lnot A_n\}$ are consistent...

Comment: If both $\Delta_n \cup \{A_n\}$ and $\Delta_n \cup \{\lnot A_n\}$ are consistent, then $\Delta_{n+1} = \Delta_n \cup \{A_n\}$.  That seems to be well-defined.  The fact that, in this case, we _could have_ chosen the other one doesn't really matter to the definition.

Comment: @BrainMoehring I see-I must show that if both $\Delta_n\cup\{A_n\}$ and $\Delta\cup\{\lnot A_n\}$ are consistent then we must have $A_n=\lnot A_n$.

Comment: @DickGrayson that's incorrect; it is *never* the case that $A_n=\neg A_n$. reread the definition of $\Delta_{n+1}$ carefully; as Brian points out, if both $\Delta_n\cup\{A_n\}$ and $\Delta_n\cup\{\neg A_n\}$ are consistent, then $\Delta_{n+1}$ is just *defined* to be $\Delta_n\cup\{A_n\}$; there's no worry about getting "two different $\Delta_{n+1}$s" because $\Delta_{n+1}$ is uniquely specified

Comment: (additionally, let me just reiterate Noah's point, which is that the statement you are trying to prove is very much not true. for example, suppose $\Delta=\varnothing$; this is consistent, and your statement (if it were true) would imply that only one of $\{A\}$ and $\{\neg A\}$ is consistent for every $A$. do you see why that's not the case?)

Comment: Late to the party, but... I am sure you remember Euclidean geometry *without "Fifth postulate"* and then two theories that you get when you add either Fifth postulate (Euclidean geometry) or its negation (non-Euclidean geometry)...

Comment: As best I can tell, you're interpreting the definition as saying "Take two statements and use whichever one works".  That would not give a well-defined definition, but that's not the given definition.  It is "Take a statement and its negation.  If the statement works, use it.  If not, use the negation [because it then necessarily works, as it's impossible for both $\Delta_n \cup \{A_n\}$ and $\Delta_n \cup \{\lnot A_n\}$ to be inconsistent if $\Delta_n$ is consistent]"

Comment: @BrianMoehring that is precisely it-I misunderstood the definition of $\Delta_n$. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom you are absolutely correct-I completely misinterpreted the definition of $\Delta_n$.